# Call Multiple XSLT maps from MAIN XSLT Map

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Can we call multiple XSLT maps from Main XSLT maps. Based on  condition match?

Sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentList>
    <List>
        <Name>Jan</Name>
        <StudentClass>10th</StudentClass>
        <AGE>13</AGE>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <Name>MARC</Name>
        <StudentClass>8th</StudentClass>
        <AGE>8</AGE>
    </Client>
</ClientList>
```

Below is a Main xslt map for me. in this xslt map based on condition i need to call other xslt maps. below code is not working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>   

   <xsl:param name="StudentClass" select="'10th'"/>
   <xsl:param name="AGE" select="'8'"/>      
   
   
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$StudentClass = '10th'">
            <xsl:include href="10thClass_Mapping.xsl"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="$AGE = '8'">
            <xsl:include href="8years_Mapping.xsl"/>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How to call multiple XSLT maps from MAIN XSLT map?

Comment: You cannot `xsl:include` stylesheets conditionally. What you need to do is call templates from those stylesheet included at the top level based on your conditions.

Comment: See answer on [How to include an XSL file into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28888360/205233) for a working example.

Comment: In addition to Martin's answer below, here is another answer with examples of static params: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103243/317052

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3, using static, global parameters and `use-when`, you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="StudentClass" static="yes" select="'10th'"/>

<xsl:include href="10thClass_Mapping.xsl" use-when="$StudentClass = '10th'"/>
```

Note that both static parameter declarations as well as any `xsl:include/xsl:import` need to be used a top level elements, i.e. children of `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform`.